# MSMQ not invoking COM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, msmq

I made a COM object with c# and let VS register it for me.  I can see it in registry and if I make a test app I can add a reference to it and it works as expected with all the methods available and functional.

Now If I try and use it in a MSMQ rule nothing happens.  It will not be invoked.  Is this because it is a .NET assembly?  Is it because I do not have VS Pro?  Do you have any idea at all?

Comment: Bump.  Just wondering if anyone has an idea.

Update.  In Wondows avent viewer, it states that the COM component could not be found.  Why can't it find it.  Everything looks good.

Comment: Update.  I HAVE VS PRO NOW and it is still NOT working.  However I got an access denied error when building my project the first time.  The second time it built fine.  But I suspect its still not registered properly.

Comment: You get the build error because VS tries to call `regasm` but that does not run without admin privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't by any chance registered your component on a mapped network drive have you? MSMQ runs in a different WinStation to the interactive WinStation. Network drives that are mapped in the interactive WinStation are not visible in other WinStations which could result in the symptom you described (component not found).

Comment: I did at first.  But then I moved my project locally, registered it with VS, and completely recreated the trigger and rule.  I still get the same event message.

I've resorted to using a windows service to listen for messages rather than the messages triggering on component.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521841/receiving-msmq-messages-with-windows-service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the system event log for error messages (eventvwr.exe). If your component is registered and MSMQ is properly configured to activate your component but it fails, most likely the problem is with permissions. The event log should contain the details of the prolem.

Comment: The event just states that the component cannot be found.  I've researched this and other people have agreed that this is a very vague message.

Answer (score 0):

Update!!!

I was messing around with this again.  I created a simple EXE to fire when a message is received.  It accepts 2 string parameters.

I forgot to pass the parameters the first time and I get the SAME error as I was discribing before.  About the COM object not being found.  I passed the parameters and it worked fine.

I thought I was passing the parameters to my COM object just fine, but maybe not.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  I will create a COM with no parameters and see if I can force the COM to invoke.

If anyone as examples of creating objects to accept parameters, please let me know.