# Receiving MSMQ messages with Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq

I'm creating a Windows Service in C#.

What is the best way to listen for messages??  How do I code this properly??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't listen. You configure [MSMQ Activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246.aspx) to activate your component when messages arrive. The link has all the details you need, code and configuration.

Comment: Yes that was my first choice.  Look here for my other question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473179/msmq-not-invoking-com

Comment: COM activation is the MSMQ 3 model. With MSMQ 4 there is a new activation model, based on Windows Activation Service and WCF.

Comment: I will look into Activation Services.

Answer (score 2):

As previously stated, MSMQ Activation is probably the best way, if you can use that.  Alternatively, here is code that I've used:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
MessageQueue q = GetQueue<T>();
while (true)
{
  try
  {
    Message msg = q.Receive(ts);
    var t = (T)msg.Body;
    HandleMessage(t);
  }
  catch (MessageQueueException e)
  {
    // Test to see if this was just a timeout.
    // If it was, just continue, there were no msgs waiting
    // If it wasn't, something horrible may have happened
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use the message enumerator function instead of Receive, you don't have to worry about getting a timeouts when the queue is empty.

Comment: Very good consultutah!  I have been out for a week and we know what that is like trying to get back into a project, but I will try some things.

Grauenwolf, can you please post a short example of Recieve?  I've researched this and I'm not completely understanding it.  Especially after being on vacation for over a week.  Thanks....

Comment: You might want to mention the whereabouts for the `GetQueue<T>()` method.