# is it possible to GetAllMessages and Purge as a transaction

Tags: msmq

Before I start processing the messages in the queue i need to harvest off all the "old" messages and deal with them.  After that I get into my read/process loop.

`GetAllMessages` will return an array of messages, howerver it does not remove them from the queue. `Purge` will remove all messages from the queue.  I need to do both as a transaction.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to deal with processing leftover messages after (re)starting a service.

A solution I implemented simply uses a configurable receive timeout to control the processing loop so your service doesn't need to bother about the state of the queue - it will process whatever is there.

Here's a simple C# sample

```
...
Message msg;
MessageQueueTransaction currentTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
TimeSpan receiveTimeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

while (MyService.IsRunning)
{
    try
    {
        currentTransaction.Begin();
        msg = this.sourceQueue.Receive(receiveTimeOut, currentTransaction);

        // process your message here

        currentTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch(MessageQueueException mqex)
    {
        switch(mqex.MessageQueueErrorCode)
        {
            case MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout :
                // That's okay ... try again, maybe there's a new message then
                break;

            default :
                // That's not okay ... abort transaction
                currentTransaction.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

I planned to extend the timeout to be dynamic in that it would increase the timeout every time the timeout exception throws and reset it as soon as a message is processed.

A short introduction is given in [Programming best Practices with MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811053.aspx) although it doesn't exactly back my proposed solution.

---

Digging a little more I found [an answer proposing MSMQ Activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521841/) which I didn't try out myself yet.

Comment: you guessed correctly -- my issue is that on the restart I have to process the messages differently, than in the normal running state.  However I take your point and will likely end up using this approach.  One of the frustrations is that the timeout throws an exception.  In my case I'm reading the queue with an literator method, and so can't catch the exception.  It's for this reason that I've delayed putting this approach in place.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: In your example, you use a 30 second timeout.  That seems like a long time to wait for an orderly shutdown. On the other hand I wonder if a short timeout, ie 2 seconds, would bog down the system.  I really dislike polling systems like this.  Is there no better way to interrupt the blocked Receive?

Comment: @Ralph The 30 sec timeout is just for the sake of this sample. I searched around some time before I implemented my service and using this timeout seems to be the way proposed by MS - I'll have to digg in my bookmarks to back this but I'll add it as a reference asap. Anyway I liked the idea better than coding a wating loop.